# Error when running a function with its dependencies with Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, spyder

I am trying to run a function with dependencies in Pyspark, but I keep receiving an error (follows the code).
My Pyspark works fine and is engaged in my Python environment and my function is also correct. I am using Python 3.6 on Spyder with Spark 2.2.0.

My code is:

```
    import flex_time
    import pathTraveltime
    import pickle
    import time
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    import pytz
    import cgitb
    cgitb.enable()
    import pyspark
    import os,sys

    os.environ['SPARK_HOME']

    sys.path.append("C:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python")
    import findspark
    findspark.init("C:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7")
    spark_home = os.environ.get("SPARK_HOME")
    sys.path.insert(0, spark_home + "python")
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, "python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src"))
    conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
    conf.set("spark.executor.memory", '4g')
    conf.set('spark.executor.cores', '16')
    conf.set('spark.cores.max', '16')
    conf.set("spark.driver.memory",'4g')
    conf.setMaster("local[2]")  # number of threads to use
    sc = pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
    sc.addPyFile('~pathTraveltime.py')
    sc.addPyFile('~flex_time.py')
    sc.addPyFile('~Prediction_X.py')
    with open('detailed_network.pickle','rb') as f:  
            graph = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
    input_json=data = 
    [{"origin_lat":38.916228,"origin_lon":-77.031576,"destination_lat":
    38.918236,"destination_lon":-77.229942,"dept_time":"23:30","before":
    60,"after":60},

    {"origin_lat":38.916228,"origin_lon":-77.031576,"destination_lat":38.918236,
    "destination_lon":-77.229942,"dept_time":"23:30","before":60,"after":60}]
    results =[]
    #Function
    def flex_func(input_json):  

         import flex_time
         import pathTraveltime


         origin_lat=input_json["origin_lat"]
         origin_lon=input_json["origin_lon"]
         destination_lat=input_json["destination_lat"]
         destination_lon=input_json["destination_lon"] 

         path = flex_time._ShortestPath(origin_lat, origin_lon, destination_lat, 
         destination_lon, graph)

         #Pyspark Code 
         count = sc.parallelize(input_json).map(lambda j: 
         flex_func(j)).collect()
```

And I keep getting this error message:

```
#Error Message
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 14, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
11 more
```